# scrollTop animate is laggy in chrome but works fine in firefox (background-size: cover issue?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scrolltop

Edit: the issue seems to be with `background-size: cover;` in my css. Searching for a remedy on google now...

This is the site: bitco.tk

When you click a link in the top navigation menu it should animate and scroll down to the elements.

It works fine in FF, IE, and Safari, but in chrome it's very laggy/choppy. here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.restLoc').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: ($('#locInfo').offset().top) -60 }, 'slow');
  });
  $('.restMenu').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: ($('#mList').offset().top) -60 }, 'slow');
  });
  $('.restName').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
  });

});
```

I have tried it without the `e.preventDefault` and `.stop()` but it doesn't make a difference.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Brunis How do you do scrollTop in css? scrollTop is not a css proprety and cannot be animated. Anyway, not all css3 transitions are hardware accelerated. I recommend GreenSock. It is a plugin for hardware accelerated javascript transitions. http://greensock.com

Comment: Impressive page load BTW. Almost instant.

Comment: @Marcel thanks, I'll check em both out.

Comment: @Marcel ah yes, it's a dom attribute, my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling I found the issue was with the CSS `background` property. The quickest solution I found was the jquery plugin 'backstretch'.